# Efficient way of storing and managing data with shared categories in c++

Tags: c++, database

I am building a finances application to track and manager my spendings and practice coding.

I have a class named "Transaction" containing all of the transaction info such as amount, vendor and description. each Transaction will have a category or two such as month "June" or type "Groceries".

my original idea was to create a vector of Transaction class pointers, and upon creation, add the instance to the corresponding vectors. the issue with this method however is that if I use an std::vector for my entire transaction storage, it'll change the internal address of the variables and therefore the pointer will be invalid, With this idea the speed up looking up transactions is very fast, and to find transactions in two categories (month, year, type) I just have to find all common elements. in the array by checking the smallest category and making sure it's in all the other ones.

I have used a std::map() so far with the key being the category, but that proves to cause issues in some ways, which is transactions with multiple categories or getting a list of all the transactions we have without copying.

I can use lists but the time complexity of my database would go up by a considerable amount.

sure I could call it a day and replace all my functions with a for() loop, I rather make my code faster.

What are you suggestions for managing this data?

I'll need to get all elements with categories(multiple or one) or the entire transaction history, or the last N amount. as I'll display it on a widget sorted by either date or amount.

Comment: Be aware that the word "transaction" in relation to databases usually has a totally different meaning. Consider using a different word to represent purchases. Perhaps also consider a battle-tested database library such as SQLite which is designed for this kind of thing and will be more robust and flexible than anything you write. Regarding your general concerns about copying and efficiency, it's important to actually measure those with targeted testing to determine if it's even relevant. Try to avoid the trap of premature optimization.

Comment: @paddy tbh the SQL advice is good, don't reinvent the wheel and all that. but the point of optimizing this is to practice my coding skills, in a real life application I'd use search O(N) and call it a day with a single vector containing everything (and move category to the transaction itself)

Comment: If you're concerned about the location of your objects changing, you can use `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`. And/or you can store indices for your references/lookups instead of pointers. I disagree with the comment about using O(N) search "in a real life application". This is something that is typically to be avoided when possible. If data is ordered, there is rarely a good case for linear search, since binary search is just as easy with `std::lower_bound`. In other cases, it's often good to create an index using `std::unordered_map` or `std::map` before doing multiple lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a std::map where the key is the category and the value is a vector of transaction pointers. This allows you to easily retrieve all transactions for a specific category. If a transaction belongs to multiple categories, you can add it to multiple vectors.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Transaction*>> transactionMap;
```

If you have a large number of categories, you can implement a hash table (with constant lookup time) by using an unordered_map like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Transaction*>> transactionHash;
```

Comment: The issue with this method is that I'd be creating a large amount of duplicates, and upon editing, I'd have to find all its copies. additionally getting transaction (the last 100) will be difficult.

Comment: @AmeliaHaghighi You may need to use multiple data structures. You can use a `std::unordered_map` for storing all transactions and a `std::multimap` for categorizing transactions. For the `unordered_map`, the key would be a unique identifier for each transaction. For the `multimap`, the key would be the category and the value would be the transaction ID. To get the last N transactions, you can keep a `std::deque` of transaction IDs and if the size of the deque or list exceeds N, you pop an ID from the back.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, where would the actual data be? cause if I use  vector for the actual Transactions the address. changes constantly and I can't point  to it's elements.

Comment: @AmeliaHaghighi The data would be allocated in heap using the `new` keyword. You just need to remember to free the data (using `delete`) before your program ends. Memory doesntYou may want to consider writing the transactions to some kind of file (e.g., JSON) so that you can close the program without losing all the transactions. But if you go that far it may be worth just looking into existing libraries like SQLite, which are designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: ^^ I got cut off mid-sentence. As I was saying, memory doesn't need to have an "owner" in C++, you just need to keep track of its location in memory using a pointer.